# I want a simple php table inside a while loop, with add or subtract

Tags: php

I am new to php and need some help please.

I'd like to create a simple php while loop.
Inside the loop I want to be able to add or subtract values.

My code seems to be doing what I want, except that i do not know what to put in the `$count` variable.

The aim is to have one table, and inside that table either add or subtract values of 5.

Here is my code.

```
<?php

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["userName"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["email"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["balance"] . "</td>";

            $count = $row["id"];

            ?>
            <td>
                <form name="form" method="post" action="">
                    <input type="submit" name="add" value="+">
                    <input type="submit" name="subtract" value="-">
                    <?php

                    if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
                        $sql2 = "UPDATE users SET balance = balance + 5 where id = $count ";
                        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST['subtract'])) {
                        $sql2 = "UPDATE users SET balance = balance - 5 where id = $count";
                        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
                    }

                   echo $row["id"];
                    ?>

                </form>
            </td>


            </tr>

            <?php
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send the row id back to the php script, not just the action 'add' or 'subtract'. You can identify the row by the id you want to update. The code will look something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'], $_POST['add'])) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE users SET balance = balance + 5 WHERE id = ?');
    if (!$stmt) {
        die('Prepare failed: '.$conn->error);
    }
    $stmt->bindParam('d', $_POST['id']);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    if (!$result) {
        die('Execute failed: '.$stmt->error);
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['id'], $_POST['substract'])) {
    // ...
}
```

You add this code before the while loop and remove the existing query stuff from inside the while loop.

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for the answer. Still struggling a bit, but will work with what you have given.